# How to contact the professor again?

Tags: graduate-admissions, advisor, email

I have applied to a university for Research Masters. Following application, I contacted the Professor I had listed on my application and told him about my research and profile. He asked me to send him my Research paper and after going through it, he contacted me again to ask about if I have a valid TOEFL and References etc. After the initial conversation of 5 emails, he hasn't contacted me again and its been 20 days.

Should I contact him or wait? I am confused about what could be the best way of contacting him again.

Comment: Try to send a more concise email, a professor must be really busy and they receive a lot of emails. For me, sending 5 emails is really a lot.

Comment: Also you need to give more details about those 5 emails, are they thoughtful and concise? or just simple chat? do you feel the prof. is bothered by your email?

Comment: He is a human being, and may have gotten quite busy and is unable to answer your emails. Or, he might be arguing your admissions case. Or he might be waiting to see if research funding is granted to support your candidacy.  You might just write a polite email saying that you are touching base, and were curious if there was an update or "no news yet" on your application.  He probably can't answer acceptance questions until all the acceptances are decided.

Comment: @azer89 What I meant was that there were 5 emails in total. 3 mine 2 his. After my first email, he replied and requested my paper. Then he replied again after going through my paper (presumably) and asked if I had TOEFL and References, which I provided. I then didn't write again.

Comment: @magi182 That's what I was thinking that he may be busy. I just am not sure about how long should I wait before asking anything about my case.

Comment: I think you are OK, don't worry about that. My adviser even rarely replies my email. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am a graduate student, though I am not getting a research masters. However, what I would do is this:

In most cases, it is a board of admissions counselors made up of multiple professors and maybe some administrative positions that will be making the decision as to whether to accept you or not. So, in that case it means that the decision to admit you into the Research Masters program would likely not lie solely on the one professor that you have listed on the application. So what I would do is contact the main office of the department that heads the research masters program that you have applied to and tell them something like 
"Hello, my name is _____. I would like to check on the status of my application. I have been in contact with professor _____ but I know that he is busy so I wanted to check with you all to make sure that you have everything that you need from me and to see when I can expect a decision to be made pertaining to my acceptance.

Sometimes calling and speaking to someone directly will get you a lot further than an e-mail, so you might need to try this method.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's been more than enough time to reach out and start the conversation up again.  The trick is to be persistent, not pushy.